# Is there any analogs of uniPlot function?

Tags: r, nvm

I was looking through some functions and found `library(MVN)`, where I wanted to use the `uniPlot` function, which is quite neat as it quickly provides summary plots for each column in data frame. I was using :

```
uniPlot(ready, type="histogram")
```

But the function was depreciated, I was wondering whether anyone knows anything similar to this function ( plot histograms with overlaying normal curve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this in the current [MVN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/index.html) version as following:

```
 mvn(data = iris[1:50,1:3], mvnTest = "royston", univariatePlot =
     "histogram")
```